# Issues on COM-Communication with Qualcomm SURF-xxxx

Tags: java, serial-port, putty, qualcomm

im a Student worker for a automobile r&d Company. Im currently working on a Java application that is workling like QXDM but also offers additional Features. I'm stuck with the communication over the DM (Diagnostic mode) port. I tried to use PuTTy for that. Putty and also my application were able to connect to that Port. Now since I got the official dmss documentation, im still not able to get a reply on that port. Do you guys have had the same Problem or at least a similar one and may provide me some help finding the issue? To Switch the phone in diagnostic mode there is a AT-Command. But even though if I connect via puTTy and write down the command, I dont get a reply in putty neither the following diagnostic requests will work.

Does anyone know how to use puTTy to give AT Commands?

The Qualcomm device is connected via USB Dongle using Telit Drivers. Using Telit Serial Diagnostics Interface COM Port.

Using QXDM everything is working fine.

Comment: Still werent able to solve this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For what it's worth now, QXDM is very extendible (thus the X) once you get a groove on how to create custom views and interact with the COM automation and by far the best logging tool of any baseband/modem chip OEM in my opinion, so any tool that directly deals with the device will have to make up A LOT of ground before you can add functionality. I would see a few good use-cases for basic functionality like just obtaining logs. In regards to AT commands, those are usually issued on a different port than the diagnostics port, with the variety of devices hard to tell.

Comment: Thus said I am happy to help if I understand a little better where you are right now, and if that is still relevant.